# Ignore spaces in Solaris 'find' output

Tags: bash, find, spaces, sunos

I am trying to remove all empty files that are older than 2 days. Also I am ignoring hidden files, starting with dot. I am doing it with this code:

```
find /u01/ -type f -size 0 -print -mtime +2 | grep -v "/\\." | xargs rm
```

It works fine until there are spaces in the name of the file. How could I make my code ignore them?

OS is Solaris.

Comment: Do you need the `-print` where it is?  If you include it, I'd expect it to be at the end of the conditions, not in the middle.

Comment: No, that is there by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

Install GNU `find` and GNU `xargs` in an appropriate location (not `/usr/bin`) and use:

```
find /u01/ -type f -size 0 -mtime +2 -name '[!.]*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

(Note that I removed (what I think is) a stray `-print` from your `find` options.  The options shown removes empty files modified more than 2 days ago where the name does not start with a `.`, which is the condition that your original `grep` seemed to deal with.)

#### Option 2

The problem is primarily that `xargs` is defined to split its input at spaces. An alternative is to write your own `xargs` surrogate that behaves sensibly with spaces in names; I've done that. You then only run into problems if the file names contain newlines — which the file system allows. Using a NUL (`'\0'`) terminator is guaranteed safe; it is the only character that can't appear in a path name (which is why GNU chose to use it with `-print0` etc).

#### Option 3

A final better option is perhaps:

```
find /u01/ -type f -size 0 -mtime +2 -name '[!.]*' -exec rm {} \;
```

This avoids using `xargs` at all and handles all file names (path names) correctly — at the cost of executing `rm` once for each file found.  That's not too painful if you're only dealing with a few files on each run.

POSIX 2008 introduces the notation `+` in place of the `\;` and then behaves rather like `xargs`, collecting as many arguments as will conveniently fit in the space it allocates for the command line before running the command:

```
find /u01/ -type f -size 0 -mtime +2 -name '[!.]*' -exec rm {} +
```

The versions of Solaris I've worked on do not support that notation, but I know I work on antique versions of Solaris.  GNU `find` does support the `+` marker and therefore renders the `-print0` and `xargs -0` workaround unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, `find /u01/ -type f -size 0 -mtime +2 -name '[!.]*' -exec rm {} \;` this works for me.